# How to use a Wordpress Gutenberg block programmatically into the theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm developing a wordpress theme 100% based on Gutenberg blocks. Some pages are built directly on the editor (eg. home page), but other pages (eg. search results) need to be coded.

I want to show my search results using a post grid block, for example.

Is it possible to call a Gutenberg block programmatically, i.e, on my theme code, sending parameters and getting the html code back? As we do with `do_shortcode()`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of the block you are interested in, most of them are written and rendered entirely in JavaScript - have a look at the [Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/) and [Dynamic Blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/)

Comment: Thanks DOBss. I see your point, but giving links for whole documentation is not helpful for me and for the others looking for the same question. If want to go further in your answer, please consider, for example, atomic blocks.